# Missing results in my array

Tags: javascript

I have an object which im converting into an array of coords which will be used to store which coords are "occupied".

I thought i had it working but on further inspection through console.log the array is missing a fair few results.

So this is basically my object:

```
var sdata = {"4":{"7":["1","7","3","3"]}};
```

In words this is:

```
var sdata = {"X":{"Y":["ID","ID","Width","Height"]}
```

Ignore ID for this as they are unrelated... but im trying to use this data so that i have the X and Y + the additional X and Y coords related to its tile dimensions width and height.

Imagine if you will the object for 4:7 is 3 by 3 dimensions so resulting in these 9 grid references would exist.

```
[4:7], [5:7], [6,7]  
[4:8], [5:8], [6,8]  
[4:9], [5:9], [6:9]
```

So my function to create the coords is :

```
function populate_collisions() {

  for (var X in sdata) {
    X = parseInt(X);

    for (var Y in sdata[X]) {
      Y = parseInt(Y);
      width = parseInt(sdata[X][Y][2]);
      height = parseInt(sdata[X][Y][3]);

  for (i=X; i!= X+width; i++) {

        if( typeof gcollision[i] == 'undefined' ) {
          gcollision[i] = new Array();
        }
        gcollision[i][Y] = 1

        for (j=Y; j!=Y+height; j++) {

          if( typeof gcollision[X] == 'undefined' ){ 
            gcollision[X] = new Array();
          }
          gcollision[X][j] = 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But my logic must be wrong because im getting this result for my array:

```
[4] [7] = 1
[4] [8] = 1
[4] [9] = 1
[5] [7] = 1
[6] [7] = 1
```

Any idea why im missing additional data?

Comment: What were you expecting to get?

Comment: I don't understand why your object is so convoluted. Surly it would be easier to just label the properties: `sdata = {x:4,  y:7, id0:1, id1:7, w:3, h:3};` then you can ditch the `parseInt` and for..in stuff. Direct property access should be faster and also you don't get tripped by someone adding an enumerable property to Object.prototype (unlikely as that might be) and your object structure is much more flexible.

Comment: @RobG Well its generated like this in PHP then json encoded before being passed to JS : http://www.paste.to/Mzc4MTU1

Comment: @MarkByers all the grid references for the 3 by 3 object starting from its X : Y position. I posted the example 3 by 3 result it should have created

Comment: Ok. You should declare all those variables though, may not be an issue but good practice to keep things in scope.

Comment: @RobG EDIT: which variables are you referring to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fixed code:

```
function populate_collisions() {

  for (var X in sdata) {
    X = parseInt(X);

    for (var Y in sdata[X]) {
      Y = parseInt(Y);
      var width = parseInt(sdata[X][Y][2]);
      var height = parseInt(sdata[X][Y][3]);

      for (var i=X; i < X+width; i++) {

        if (!gcollision[i]) {
          gcollision[i] = [];
        }
        gcollision[i][Y] = 1;

        for (var j=Y; j < Y+height; j++) {
```

In the next part, you were using `X`, which is always 4 so you were just overwriting that array. Use `i` instead of `X`.

You don't need the if test, since the array is created above, unless you really meant `gcollision[X][j]` or similar. I don't know as I don't know the structure you want for the `gcollision` object.

```
/*
          if (!gcollision[i][j]) { 
            gcollision[i][j] = [];
          }
*/          
          gcollision[i][j] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the record, the resulting object (assuming `gcollision` has no other properties) is:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(gcollision));
/*
{"4":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,1,1,1],
 "5":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,1,1,1],
 "6":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,1,1,1]}
*/
```

All those nulls don't exist, the arrays are sparse, but that's how JSON represents them.

Comment: Ah perfect :) I couldn't get my head around it ! No idea how you can figure it out from my badly worded question :P

Comment: If there are nested incrementing loops, chances are the inner ones need to use counters from the outer ones. I didn't know what you wanted to actually get though, glad it worked. :-)

Comment: There is no need for `!===`, simple `!=` will do since `typeof` always returns a string (but you might feel better for using strict equality). Since this seems to be for a game and you may want maximum speed, instead of `if (typeof gcollision[x] != 'undefined')` you might try `if (x in gcollision)`.

Comment: If you believe [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/typeof-vs-in-test), `in` is a lot faster (except for IE 6) and a lot less to type, so not much to recommend `typeof` instead.

Comment: OH thanks for the tip there , yes performance is a big thing for me to keep an eye on for my game ! :)

Comment: what about when i do the double check because i also have some thing similiar where i check collisions[i][j] ... is there a way to do  the  IN function for two keys?

Comment: `if ( i in collisions && j in collisions[i] )` perhaps? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that I don't entirely understand the desired output, but this seems to be what you want.

```
var sdata = {"4":{"7":["1","7","3","3"]}},
    result = [],
    x_arr;
for (var X in sdata) {
    for (var Y in sdata[X]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < sdata[X][Y][2]; i++) {
            x_arr = [];
            result.push(x_arr);
            for (var j = 0; j < sdata[X][Y][3]; j++) {
                x_arr.push((+X + j) + ':' + (+Y + i))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used string concatenation for each Array member. Wasn't sure exactly what you meant by `[4:7]`.

The result is...

```
[["4:7", "5:7", "6:7"], 
 ["4:8", "5:8", "6:8"], 
 ["4:9", "5:9", "6:9"]]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mPM96/

---

Perhaps you intended this.

```
var sdata = {"4": {"7": ["1", "7", "3", "3"]}},
    result = [];
for (var X in sdata) {
    for (var Y in sdata[X]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < sdata[X][Y][2]; i++) {
            result[+X + i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < sdata[X][Y][3]; j++) {
                result[+X + i][+Y + j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My desired result is what is shown at the very bottom, only it is not loading the 9 coords (as the object is 3by3). Will your's still work if i convert them to ints or something ? =/ Bit confused by you're method.

Comment: @Dave: So you want the outer Array to have members at indices `4,5,6`, and each member will have a nested Array with the value `1` at indices `7,8,9`? I updated with that solution. JavaScript has nested Arrays, not really multidimensional arrays.